# Date find from table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables milestone and ioi.
I have to find the date from ioi and if it is not there then i need to take date from milestone table. In IOI i have submitted date and in milestone I have Actual,forecast and baseline date.
If submitted date is not present then i need to choose the date from milestone in the availability order actual, forecast and baseline

Milestone:

```
Project_id actual_date baseline_date forecast_date
1          15-10-2018  null          12-07-2018
2          null        null          10-05-2018
```

IOI:

```
Project Id submitted_dt
1          15-09-2018
2          Null
```

For project id 1 it should be 15-09-2018
For project id 2 it should be 10-05-2018

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a coalesce:

```
select
  i.project_id,
  coalesce (i.submitted_dt, m.actual_date, m.forecast_date, m.baseline_date) as project_dt
from
  ioi i
  left join milestone m on m.project_id = i.project_id
```